# What is the name of Proto-Germanic e/ē lengthening?

Tags: proto-germanic

What is the name of Proto-Germanic e/ē lengthening before ō?
*kw**e**laną *kw**ē**lō
*wr**e**kaną *wr**ē**kō
*spr**e**kaną *spr**ē**kō
*fr**e**hnaną *fr**ē**gō
I know that e/ē lengthening before "i" is Vṛddhi gerundive?
*n**e**maną *n**ē**miz
*kw**e**þaną *kw**ē**diz
*wr**e**kaną *wr**ē**kiz

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of sound laws associated with any language, they won't all get their own pithy name. This is just "the lengthening that happens when an ō-stem noun is derived from a strong verb". You might call this a vṛddhi-derivation (*vṛddhi* being a Sanskrit word used for the strongest grade of a vowel in a given system of vowel gradation), but that's a broader category of things than just lengthened ō-stems derived from strong verbs.

"Vṛddhi gerundive" isn't the name for lengthening of **e* before **i*; **nēmiz*, **kwēdiz*, &c. are gerundives (a type of verbal adjective), and they're called *vṛddhi* because they have a lengthened grade in the root. This lengthening is part of the process of derivation, not phonologically conditioned by the following **i*: cf. the vṛddhi-gerundives **lēgaz* from ** ligjaną ~ legjaną*, **frōdaz* from **fraþjaną*, **gōdaz* from **gadaną*, &c., all without the **i*.

Comment: Oh, ō-stem _nouns_! I was looking at the question and reading the forms as 1sg present forms and wondering if I’d missed something fundamental about Germanic verbs…